# PHP MySQL Query Syntax Error?

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax, unity-game-engine

I think i'm doing something wrong here, I'm very new to PHP and only using it to interface my database with my client software through a WWW call, I have a Insert script, which works, but as for my Update script im stumped... here are the queries I tried:

the newest one:

```
$query = "UPDATE accounts SET moonscore= ' " . $moonscore . " ', sunscore = ' " . $sunscore . " ' WHERE name = ' " . $name . "';";
```

and I also tried, which I figured was wrong after awhile.

```
$query = "UPDATE accounts SET moonscore = $moonscore, sunscore = $sunscore WHERE name =$name;
```

Would really appreciate the help from all you PHP gurus.

Comment: It would help us out a lot if you told us what the exact error was, what the values of the three variables are, and separated your query onto multiple lines

Comment: Have you used mysql_error() to output any errors?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$query = "UPDATE accounts
          SET    moonscore = '$moonscore', 
                 sunscore = '$sunscore'
          WHERE  name ='$name'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you should use single quotes around the variables ,try this

```
    $query = "UPDATE accounts SET moonscore = '$moonscore' , sunscore = '$sunscore' WHERE name ='$name';
```

tips: try to use `PDO` or `MYSQLI` instead of `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is open for SQL Injections. I've added a simple function that always served me well.

```
function inject($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    // Quote if not integer
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    return $value;
}

$query = "UPDATE accounts SET moonscore = ".inject($moonscore).", sunscore = ".inject($sunscore)." WHERE name =".inject($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at prepared statements to avoid having to think about protecting your queries against injection with some fancy functions. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Here's a video that might give you more insight as a beginner: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bw54BqS2UE